# Echoing values from class PHP

Tags: php, oop, static, echo

I'm noob in PHP, help me please, why it dosen't echo values from my class? Maybe in PHP work with values in class is going by the specific way (I came from Java/C#) ?

```
<?php

class GuestBook
{
    private static $numInstances = 0;
    private $var1 = 10;

    function __construct()
    {
        $numInstances++;
    }

    public static function getNumInstances()
    {
        return $numInstances;
    }

    public function getVar1()
    {
        return $var1;
    }
}

$instance1 = new GuestBook();
$instance2 = new GuestBook();

echo(GuestBook::getNumInstances());
echo($instance1->getVar1());
```

?>

Comment: Notice one thing, which you didn't do in your class definition code: ***GuestBook::** getNumInstances()*. Now in the class itself you can refer to the class with `self` for static properties and methods.

Comment: Echo syntax is wrong. Check this http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_echo.asp.

Comment: in java you can but in php you cannot access class varibles like `$numInstances`

Comment: Right now your code *at least tries* to change/return local variables, not class properties. (Turn on error reporting to get some errors :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your class to:

```
class GuestBook
{
    private static $numInstances = 0;
    private $var1 = 10;

    function __construct()
    {
        static::$numInstances++;
    }

    public static function getNumInstances()
    {
        return static::$numInstances;
    }

    public function getVar1()
    {
        return $this->var1;
    }
}
```

Will output:

`210`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, I made mistake at my code: $var1 must be usual value, not static. So your code helps me with static value, how echo the non-static value from class?

Comment: Thank so much bro)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

class GuestBook
{
    private static $numInstances = 0;
    private static $var1 = 10;

    function __construct()
    {
        static::$numInstances++;
    }

    public static function getNumInstances()
    {
        return GuestBook::$numInstances;
    }

    public function getVar1()
    {
        return GuestBook::var1;
    }
}

$instance1 = new GuestBook();
$instance2 = new GuestBook();

echo(GuestBook::getNumInstances());

?>
```

you need to access the static variables using class name instead of object name

you need to use -> for non static methods